# displaying images from url, which one is faster, uimageview vs uiwebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiimageview

In my app I will have a table which one will be consisting of images that are stored in my server. So for every image, its url is available.

if thhese images are more than 25 for example, and each image has size of about 10KB, which one is faster?

```
If I place in my cell a webview and view the url
```

or

```
If I place in my cell a uiimageview and fetch image from url and set is source?
```

Comment: may be you already know about [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) it is very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

You said you are using UITableView. Right ? Then you can apply lazy loading of images to the UITableViewCells. It means it loads the images for the cells that are visible first.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Listings/Classes_LazyTableAppDelegate_m.html

this will solve your issues, its given by apple and this is the method how you you should do it

Answer (score 0):

Earlier i had faced the same problem,
then i found the EgoImageLoading classes, which are open source, you can get those classes here https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading.

The syntax is same like UIImageView.

```
        EGOImageView *imageView = [[EGOImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 9, 100, 95)];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imageView.imageUrl = yourUrl;
        imageView.placeholderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LoadingImg.gif"];
        [view addSubview:imageView];
```

This class is providing to us,show placeholder image up to loading actual image, and it will store that image in cache once it loaded, next time onwards it will read from cache.

I think it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

- **UIImageView-** when load image as URL its take time.
- **UIWebView**  - When load image as URL its looking fast when updating profile like.

> We can fix the image cache problem on loading imageview with same URL
>   Name after updating image.

EX: before uploading imageview URL as **someURL\path\user_7.png**
After uploading image API response for same URL.That time we will use this.